# Find combined code coverage of unit tests and integration tests written in different maven projects

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage

```
-Project-A(API)
----src
    ---main(Main code is written here)
    ---test(Contains Service layer tests)
---pom.xml

-Project-B(APIClientTests)
----src
    ---main
    ---test(Contains Client tests)
---pom.xml
```

My project structure looks like this. I would like to know that is there any way to calculate code coverage of code written in main of Project A, by running the integration tests written in Project A and JUnit tests written in project B.

Comment: you using any plug in for this within maven ??

Comment: Yes, I am using all the plugins and dependencies required by Spring Roo. Plugins used are tomcat7-maven-plugin, maven-shade-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin for project A and maven dependency plugin, surefire plugin, compiler plugin, build-helper-maven-plugin for project B. Also, I am using Swagger as interface to REST-API(project-A) as a testing console.

Comment: take a look at https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Use Jacoco and parent pom :

1. parent pom

   ```
   +Project-A
   +Project-B
   ```
2. in parent pom :

   ```
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
           <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   ```